# Add milliseconds to date in SQL, not seconds

Tags: timestamp, hana, milliseconds, hana-sql-script

I'm writing a procedure on the SAP HANA database (using SPS 07).

In this procedure I save the current timestamp in a variable:

```
vMyTimestamp := CURRENT_UTCTIMESTAMP;
```

I know from HANA's SQL and System Views Reference that there are currently 5 functions available to add an amount of time to a date:

- ADD_YEARS
- ADD_MONTHS
- ADD_DAYS
- ADD_WORKDAYS
- ADD_SECONDS

However, what I need is to add only a certain amount of milliseconds to a date, so for example if the current timestamp is something like *2014-04-10 09:11:45.**0*** I want to get *2014-04-10 09:11:45.**1***

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `ADD_SECONDS` with value 0.001?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add the seconds as a fractional value (e.g., `0.1 seconds = 100 milliseconds`).  The following, adds 100 milliseconds to the given timestamp:

```
SELECT ADD_SECONDS (TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-10 09:11:45'), 0.1) FROM DUMMY
```

Comment: Didn't think about that. Works like charm - thank you! And also thanks to @rs.